# What is a correct way to layer styling before begin time of core animation?

Tags: ios, swift, core-animation, calayer

I created a function with Core Animation that animate the layer height from 0 to N and it's delayable.

```
extension CALayer {
    func animate(to height: CGFloat, duration: Double, delay: Double) {
        let animation: CABasicAnimation = .init(keyPath: "bounds.size.height")

        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = height
        animation.beginTime = CACurrentMediaTime() + delay
        animation.duration: duration
        animation.timingFunction = .init(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

        // I want to improvement this part.
        //
        // self.isHidden = true
        //
        // DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
        //     self.isHidden = false
        // }

        self.bounds.size.height = height
        self.add(animation, forKey: "bounds.size.height")
    }
}
```

And the layer does transform well during animation, but it returns to original height before begin time and after finish. So I had to set `isHidden` of layer according to time to delay.

But I don't think it's a safe way. So I want to improvement that code.

What do you usually do in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `animation.fillMode = .backwards`. I think that will make the animation will apply its `fromValue` to the layer until the animation's `beginTime` is reached.

Comment: Thank you! In addition, I had to write "animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards". :)